# How to import a module from the static using dynamic import of es6?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to add dynamic import into my code to have a better performance on the client-side. So I have a webpack config where is bundling js files. On SFCC the bundled files are in the static folder where the path to that files is something like this: `/en/v1569517927607/js/app.js)`

I have a function where I'm using dynamic import of es6 to call a module when the user clicks on a button. The problem is that when we call for that module, the browser doesn't find it because the path is wrong.

`/en/lazyLoad.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

This is normal because the file is on `/en/v1569517927607/js/lazyLoad.js`.

There is a way to get it from the right path? Here is my code.

```
window.onload = () => {
    const lazyAlertBtn = document.querySelector("#lazyLoad");

    lazyAlertBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "lazyLoad" */ '../modules/lazyLoad').then(module => {
            module.lazyLoad();
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it using the Merchant Tools > SEO > Dynamic Mapping module in Business Manager.

There you can use a rule like the following to redirect the request to the static folder:

```
**/*.bundle.js i s,,,,,/js/{0}.bundle.js
```

All my chunk files are named with the `<module>.bundle` pattern.

Here you can find more info :
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/search_engine_optimization/b2c_dynamic_mappings.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll likely need to do some `path.resolve()` magic in either your import statement or your `webpack.config.js` file as is shown in the accepted answer to this question: [Set correct path to lazy-load component using Webpack - ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347293/set-correct-path-to-lazy-load-component-using-webpack-es6)

Answer (score 1):

We did it in a different way. That required two steps

1. From within the template file add a script tag that creates a global variable for the static path. Something like

```
// inside .isml template
<script>
    // help webpack know about the path of js scripts -> used for lazy loading
    window.__staticPath__ = "${URLUtils.httpsStatic('/')}";
</script>
```

2. Then you need to instruct webpack to know where to find chunks by changing `__webpack_public_path__` at runtime

```
// somewhere in your main .js file
// eslint-disable-next-line
__webpack_public_path__ = window.__staticPath__ + 'js/';
```

Optional step:

You might also want to remove code version from your `__staticPath__` using replace (at least we had to do that)

`__webpack_public_path__ = window.__staticPath__.replace('{YOUR_CODE_VERSION_GOES_HERE}', '') + 'js/';`

Comment: This one worked of me